# How to change color of the back button on SeachView

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am unable to change color of searchview back button to white color when it is in expand mode.

Here is my screen shot 
[image]

Comment: hey @gaurav-lamba did you solve this eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same problem and fixed it by setting the

**app:collapseIcon**

attribute in the toolbar. Not documented very well :)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight"
         app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapseBackIcon" />
```

Comment: dont be confused. app:collapseIcon="@drawable/collapseBackIcon". actually use APP: not android:

Answer (score 0):

create your own searchview instead using of default.. then You can anything with your custom searchview.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@color/newshour_red"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp">

<ImageView
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/backbtn"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/ivLeftHeader"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/leftMenuSearch"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_search_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:queryHint="@string/search_text"/>
</LinearLayout>`
```